# URL redirection

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am not sure if this is the right place but I need some help in the redirection of page. 
Example:
I have two SharePoint communication site abc.com and xyz.com.
abc.com is for staff
xyz.com is for students
There is one more modern page 123.com
I need if the staff go to 123.com it redirects to abc.com and if student go to 123.com it should redirect to xyz.com.
Please help me in this query

Answer (score 0):

You can get the logged-in user details and based on that can redirect to the specific page using the javascript code, below is the example where if the logged-in user matches with specific email-ID will be redirected to a different page - similarly, you can create two different home pages for:

1. Staff home page
2. Student home page

And based on the user logged-in - you can redirect to their respective page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
var currentLoggedInUser;
function init()
{
this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.objWeb = clientContext.get_web();
currentLoggedInUser = this.objWeb.get_currentUser();
this.clientContext.load(currentLoggedInUser);
this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded()
{
document.getElementById('currentUserLoginName').innerHTML = currentLoggedInUser.get_loginName();
document.getElementById('currentUserEmailID').innerHTML = currentLoggedInUser.get_email();
document.getElementById('currentUserTitle').innerHTML = currentLoggedInUser.get_title();
document.getElementById('currentUserId').innerHTML = currentLoggedInUser.get_id();

/*Once current logged in user is found with the Test1@test.com - this will be redirected to a different page.*/

If(currentLoggedInUser.get_email() =="Test1@test.com")

{
var url= "https://yoursite/sites/sitepages/your_site_page_for_the _dedicated user.aspx";
window.location = url;

}

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
{
alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

For details refer to the below article :

[How to redirect the specific user to a different page in SharePoint online?](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/verified-how-to-redirect-the-specific-user-to-a-different-page-in-sharepoint-online/)

[Get the modern script editor web part for SharePoint online modern page, from here.](https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4)

**How to redirect to another page from the mobile browser?**

Not all mobile devices support javascript and the way handling redirection from the mobile browser is different, we can use the below code to redirect to another page in the mobile device.

```
Redirecting...
<script language="javascript">
  <!--
  if(!window.location.search.substring(1) == "full=true") { // do not redirect if querystring is ?full=true
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Blackberry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/WebOs/i)) { // detect mobile browser
      window.location.replace("http://url-of-your-mobile-page"); // redirect if mobile browser detected
    }
  }
  -->
</script>
```

Reference:

[Javascript that will detect a mobile browse and redirect to another page, unless a querystring parameter of full=true exists](https://gist.github.com/critzjm/768104)

Comment: Checked the code but it dose not redirect

Comment: Current Logged-In User Information: are displayed but do not redirect.@SPM

Comment: Hi - it worked for me... just try to add a script editor web part in your any of the page and try to redirect to another page using just below line :var url= "https://yoursite/sites/sitepages/your_site_page_for_the _dedicated user.aspx"; window.location = url;

Comment: Now it worked but when i use the link in mobile it dosent redirect.

Comment: Hi - way of redirecting in mobile browser is different, please see the updated answer. If this answered has helped you, please mark it answered, it will help to the upcoming visitors. For mobile related issue, suggesting to raise a different question. Thank you!!!

Comment: I tried the mentioned code, it is not working. I am using note 10+